# Why using declaration is needed when an overload is deleted

Tags: c++, class, scope, function-declaration, using-declaration

Why do I have to reintroduce the name of a function having some of its overloads deleted ?

```
#include <string>

struct A
{
    void f(int) {}
    void f(double) {}
    void f(const std::string&) {}
};

struct B : public A
{
    using A::f; // needed to compile : why ?
    void f(int)=delete;
    void f(double)=delete;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.f(std::string("toto"));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single declaration of `f` in the `B` class hides *all* declarations of `f` from the base `A` class.

And even marking the functions as deleted is considered a declaration.

Answer (score 2):

These records within the structure B

```
void f(int)=delete;
void f(double)=delete;
```

are declarations that hide the declarations with the same name f in the base structure A.

So the using declaration in B

```
using A::f; // needed to compile : why ?
```

makes all functions with the name f declared in A visible in the structure B.

Consider the following demonstrative program where in one case there is no using declaration and in the second case there is a using declarations.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
{   
    struct A
    {
        void f( char ) const
        {
        std::cout << "A::f( char ) const\n";
        }
    };

    struct B : A
    {
        void f( int ) const
        {
            std::cout << "B::f( int ) const\n";
        }
    };


    B b;
    
    b.f( 'A' );
}

std::cout << '\n';

{   
    struct A
    {
        void f( char ) const
        {
        std::cout << "A::f( char ) const\n";
        }
    };

    struct B : A
    {
        using A::f;
        void f( int ) const
        {
            std::cout << "B::f( int ) const\n";
        }
    };


    B b;
    
    b.f( 'A' );
}

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
B::f( int ) const

A::f( char ) const
```

Answer (score 1):

It's legalistic, but at least it's consistent.

I think you're thinking that when a function is overridden in a derived class, the mechanism there is that the function from the base class, or at least its identifier, is conceptually imported into the derived class and *then* overridden. But really, what's happening is that code which calls `b.f` never even *sees* `A::f`, because the lookup succeeds before it gets there. All that happens before overload resolution takes place.

So if you want to have access to the various overloads from `A` alongside those of `B` (including the deleted ones), you need to import them into `B`, so the compiler doesn't give up before seeing them.